# Parse YAML with dots delimiter in keys

Tags: python, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

We use YAML configuration for services scaling. Usually it goes like this:

```
service:
  scalingPolicy:
    capacity:
      min: 1
      max: 1
```

So it's easy to open with basic PyYAML and parse as an dict to get `config['service']['scalingPolicy']['capacity']['min']` result as `1`. Problem is that some configs are built with dots delimiter e.g:

```
service.scalingPolicy.capacity:
  min: 1
  max: 1
```

Basic consumer of this configs is Java's Spring and somehow it's treated equally as the example above. But due to need to also parse these configs with Python - I get whole dot separated line as a `config['service.scalingPolicy.capacity']` key.

The question is - how would I make python parse any kind of keys combinations (both `separated by dots` and separated by `tabulation and :`). I didn't find related parameters for Python YAML libs (I've checked standard PyYAML and `ruamel.yaml`) and handling any possible combination manually seems like a crazy idea. The only possible idea I have is to write my own parser but maybe there is something I'm missing so I won't have to reinvent the bicycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not trivial, it is much more easy to split a lookup with a key with
dots into recursing into a nested data structure. Here you have a nested
data structure and different `[key]` lookups mean different things
at different levels.

If you use `ruamel.yaml` in the default round-trip mode, you can add a class-variable
to the type that represents a mapping, that defines on what the keys were split and an instance variable
that keeps track of the prefix already matched:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.compat import ordereddict
from ruamel.yaml.comments import merge_attrib

yaml_str = """\
service.scalingPolicy.capacity:
  min: 1
  max: 1
"""


def mapgetitem(self, key):
    sep = getattr(ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap, 'sep')
    if sep is not None: 
        if not hasattr(self, 'splitprefix'):
           self.splitprefix = ''
        if self.splitprefix:
            self.splitprefix += sep + key
        else:
            self.splitprefix = key
        if self.splitprefix not in self:
            for k in self.keys():
                if k.startswith(self.splitprefix):
                    break
                else:
                    raise KeyError(self.splitprefix)
            return self
        key = self.splitprefix
        delattr(self, 'splitprefix') # to make the next lookup work from start
    try:
        return ordereddict.__getitem__(self, key)
    except KeyError:
        for merged in getattr(self, merge_attrib, []):
            if key in merged[1]:
                return merged[1][key]
        raise

old_mapgetitem = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap.__getitem__ # save the original __getitem__
ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap.__getitem__ = mapgetitem
ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap.sep = '.'

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
# yaml.preserve_quotes = True
config = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print('min:', config['service']['scalingPolicy']['capacity']['min'])
print('max:', config['service']['scalingPolicy']['capacity']['max'])
print('---------')
config['service']['scalingPolicy']['capacity']['max'] = 42
# and dump with the original routine, as it uses __getitem__
ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap.__getitem__ = old_mapgetitem
yaml.dump(config, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
min: 1
max: 1
---------
service.scalingPolicy.capacity:
  min: 1
  max: 42
```

Comment: Indeed not a trivial task but your solution works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternative solution with pyyaml. The strategy is convert the dict into a string with the format "k1.k2.k3: value" and then convert it into a dict. Probably not the most efficient, but it works.

```
import yaml
from copy import deepcopy

my_yaml = """
service.scalingPolicy.capacity:
    min: 1
    max: 50
"""


class YamlUtils:

    def yaml_dict_to_text(self, yaml_dict, parent_key, yaml_text):
        return_value = yaml_text.split('\n')
        for key, value in yaml_dict.items():
            key_string = key
            if parent_key != "":
                key_string = parent_key + "." + key_string
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                return_value.append(self.yaml_dict_to_text(value, key_string, yaml_text))
            else:
                return_value.append("{0}: {1}".format(
                    key_string,
                    value
                )
                )
        return '\n'.join(return_value)

    @staticmethod
    def convert_to_dict(source_string, split_symbol='.', value=None):
        return_value = value
        elements = source_string.split(split_symbol)
        for element in reversed(elements):
            if element:
                return_value = {element: return_value}
        return return_value

    def dict_of_dicts_merge(self, x, y):
        z = {}
        try:
            overlapping_keys = x.keys() & y.keys()
            for key in overlapping_keys:
                z[key] = self.dict_of_dicts_merge(x[key], y[key])
            for key in x.keys() - overlapping_keys:
                z[key] = deepcopy(x[key])
            for key in y.keys() - overlapping_keys:
                z[key] = deepcopy(y[key])
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error merging dicts:", x, y, str(e))
        return z

    def text_to_yaml_dict(self, yaml_text):
        return_value = {}
        yaml_list = yaml_text.split('\n')
        for line in yaml_list:
            line_items = line.split(':')
            if len(line_items) >= 2:
                line_key = line_items[0]
                line_value = line_items[1].lstrip()
                line_dict = self.convert_to_dict(line_key, '.', line_value)
                return_value = self.dict_of_dicts_merge(return_value, line_dict)
        return return_value


def main():
    try:
        yaml_dict = yaml.safe_load(my_yaml)
        yaml_utils = YamlUtils()
        processed_yaml_text = yaml_utils.yaml_dict_to_text(
            yaml_dict,
            "",
            "",
        )
        processed_yaml_dict = yaml_utils.text_to_yaml_dict(processed_yaml_text)
        print("Min:", processed_yaml_dict['service']['scalingPolicy']['capacity']['min'])
        print("Max:", processed_yaml_dict['service']['scalingPolicy']['capacity']['max'])
        data = yaml.dump(processed_yaml_dict, indent=True)
        print("New yaml:", data)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```